# Having multiple Address types and associations with Model, using a polymorphic way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let an User and Event models.

I would like to add an Address model with those usecases:

- Address has different types, for instance BillingAddress, DeliveryAddress, etc. (should I use inheritence?)
- User can have multiple addresses of different types. For instance, a user can have 2 billing addresses and 3 delivery addresses.
- Event can also have multiple addresses of different types.

What is the easiest way to handle such use cases in Rails?
Or is there any gem to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

### Polymorphism

In your Address model you can use a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) to have an address belong to different parent models, given you made the correct migration:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
end
```

#### Data migration

You can simply do the following

```
$ rails g migration AddAddressableToAddresses addressable:references:polymorphic
```

If you want to do it manually, a polymorphic association simply adds an id, a type and an index on both:

```
def change 
  add_column :addresses, :addressable_id, :integer
  add_column :addresses, :addressable_type, :string
  add_index :addresses, [:addressable_id, :addressable_type]
end
```

### Single Table Inheritance (STI)

Regarding the different type of addresses, with different validation strategies and methods [Single Table Inheritance can be a solution](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance). You'll be able to do thinks like `event.addresses` and get all the addresses of an event with their type associated.

Comment: Do you have an example of the migration?

Comment: With your answer, how do you handle multiple address types for an User?
Like doing:
`class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :billing_addresses, as: :addressable
  has_many :shipping_addresses, as: :addressable
end`

Comment: With STI you simply add a `type:string` attribute to your address model, then you inherit your different adresses from that base Address model:  `class Address < ApplicationRecord` `class ShippingAddress < Address` and so on. You can then just add `has_many :shipping_addresses, as: addressable`

Comment: What is the advantages of this second approach?